# QGIS Bug? Table of attributes zooms-in to a wrong feature

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I have encountered a strange QGIS behavior while zooming-in to a record in an attribute table.
Below is a highlighted row of the attribute table which I zoomed in into map:

[image]

Then I used an Identify tool directly on the map and received different attribute data:
[image]

It is apparent that the attributes are different, and the ones obtained with the Identify tool are correct. I have double-checked whether the identified feature that was zoomed in is the same.

I am using QGIS 3.32.0-Lima

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Does this happen with all point or only some ? did you have multipoint geometry ? does all your point have a geometry ? (also just to be sure could it be some superposed point ?)

Comment: This can happen if there are duplicates in the "primary" key, or if the key is not well defined (ex: if it is computed in a database based on the rowid without having defined a definite sort order)

Comment: Is it possible that you have the attribute table of layer 1 in view and zoom to a feature, but in the layer overview pane (left) another layer 2 is active. Now, if you use the identify tool, you'll receive the information of the 2nd layer. I just would like to exclude this option, since the attributes in the two screenshots are partially different.

Comment: I relised that I made some edits in the layer, namely splitting lines in a point with the advanced editing toolbar and split object tool. After that I was sorting the table by attributes in the editing mode. Finally I deleted some of the objects based on selection on screan (not by attributes). This means that I do not have the original layer that caused the problem now ;( . When I tried to duplicate the layer that caused problems before it is fine. Only for the attributes that were causing problems I get different OBJECTID attributes.

Comment: @ J.R. This happened only with selected points. I do not think I had multiple geometry, nor there was point superimposed on the feature.

Comment: @ JGH: please explain how I could check this and fix in the future.

Comment: @ Vincé: this was not possible, I checked whether the Identify tool selects the proper layer. The attributes are partially the same, but this is ok.